# Rails + PostgreSQL: if value in one column is NULL, search by a value in a different column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

In my model, I have these columns:

```
customer_invoiced_at: datetime
customer_invoice_at_custom: datetime
```

I am trying to search all records where the given date matches `customer_invoiced_at`:

```
scope :by_customer_invoiced_at_from, (lambda do |date_from|
    self.where("customer_invoiced_at >= ?", date_from.to_datetime.beginning_of_day) if date_from.present?
end)
```

I'd need to tweak it a bit - if `customer_invoice_at_custom` exists (is not null or empty), I would need to use this field instead of `customer_invoiced_at`. However, if `customer_invoice_at_custom` is NULL or empty, I'd want to use `customer_invoiced_at` (as it is now in the shown scope).

How do I achieve that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use PostgreSQL's native `COALESCE()` function? This does exactly what you want:

```
.where("COALESCE(customer_invoiced_at, my_other_column) >= ?", date_from.to_datetime.beginning_of_day)
```